# Json deserialization return null

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to deserialize this [json](http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_tables?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8&callback_params=%7B%22season_id%22%3A11663%2C%22round_id%22%3A31554%2C%22outgroup%22%3Afalse%7D&action=changeTable&params=%7B%22type%22%3A%22competition_league_table%22%7D).
Actual I stay using the `simple html dom` library for get the web content, so the next step that I do is using the `json_decode()` function. But when I'll print the value returned by the function I get `NULL`. This is the code:

```
<?php

require_once("simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_tables?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8&callback_params=%7B%22season_id%22%3A11663%2C%22round_id%22%3A31554%2C%22outgroup%22%3Afalse%7D&action=changeTable&params=%7B%22type%22%3A%22competition_league_table%22%7D');
$decoded = json_decode($html,true);

var_dump($decoded);

?>
```

What's wrong in my code? Maybe this isn't the best way for doing this? Hint me.

Comment: `file_get_html()` returns a PHP object not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your file_get_html function is not working properly, you can get the content of a web with `file_get_contents`

```
<?php

    $html = file_get_contents('http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_tables?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8&callback_params=%7B%22season_id%22%3A11663%2C%22round_id%22%3A31554%2C%22outgroup%22%3Afalse%7D&action=changeTable&params=%7B%22type%22%3A%22competition_league_table%22%7D');
    $decoded = json_decode($html,true);

    var_dump($decoded);

?>
```

Comment: Yeah! You're right! In this case the best choice is using file_get_contents instead of file_get_html